# Got unexpected reserved word after installing serverless offline

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-offline

I installed serverless-offline with the following command

```
npm install serverless-offline --save-dev
```

This is the version that was installed:

```
"serverless-offline": "^10.0.0"
```

and have added plugins at the bottom of my yaml file:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Now when I run a serverless command, I get the following error:
[image]

Not sure what's going on.

p.s. Before installing the serverless-offline, the serverless commands were all working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your version of nodeJs matches the version of nodeJs you have in your `serverless.yml`.

I had the same problem because I was using nodejs**12** and I set up nodejs**14** in my `serverless.yml`. Upgrade to nodejs14 fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me here was due to `serverless-offline` version `12.0.4`.
I downgraded to version `^8.7.0` which fixed the problem for me.